# How to display Text in Arabic in UIlabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, arabic

I am getting this string from server in response, which is actually in arabic
"`&#1606;&#1585;&#1610;&#1583; &#1571;&#1606; &#1606;&#1585;&#1609; &#1607;&#1584;&#1575; &#1601;&#1610; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1594;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;`"

You can see this text in arabic on browser like this : نريد أن نرى هذا في اللغة العربية browser automatically shows text in arabic. for former i have put code tag so it is showing codes...

Now I want to show it on UILabel in arabic fonts, how would I do that?

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just converting those HTML entities to UTF?

Comment: Like this? char *temp = [arabicCodeStr UTF8String]; NSLog(@"text:%s",temp);, but it doesn't output arabic it just gives codes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert each 4 text digit decimal number in the server response string to a C int, then you can convert each character to an NSString using something like:

```
int c = ... /* your 4 text digit unicode ordinal converted to an integer */
charString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c ];
```

You might also be able to ask a UIWebView to run a line of Javascript and return an NSString.