# NSXMLParser and the "£" symbol

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, currency, xml-parsing

Hey all, slight problem when i read in an XML form. 
NSXMLParse correctly see's the "£" symbol but its prints out the unicode, \U00a3.

I am just reading it to a string.

```
   [pre_Currency appendString:[self cleanString:string]];
```

CleanString removes \n - \t and i even added parsing out the unicode and replace it with the Char symbol for the "£".

Oddly enough a NSLog here print a "£" symbol, but when it didEndElement i add it to the dictionary,

```
    [number setObject:[self cleanString:pre_Currency] forKey:@"pre_currency"];
```

It add it as a unicode Char.

Cant understand why, looking at google theres very little aimed at parsing unicode chars.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but might be useful to you,if you use the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method

```
NSString *specialChars=@"YOur string with special characters."

specialChars=[specialChars stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\U00a3" withString:@"£"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah tried this but when you use @"\00a3" you get an error saying something about non complete universal char name, removing the '\' helps but its still not being picked up.

Comment: thats @"\U00a3", just dont understand how it goes from one format to another between, foundCharacters, to didEndElement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it happens for symbols and for other languages fonts in they are not in english, I also got reply here that we will have to decode it as follows:

```
int c = ... /* your 4 text digit unicode ordinal converted to an integer */
charString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c ];
```

Original link - [How to display Text in Arabic in UIlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211160/how-to-display-text-in-arabic-in-uilabel)